# CSS Positioning Sticky and fixed not working as expected

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

[image]I am trying to make the first and last section to be fixed and only the middle section to be able to scroll down while keeping the navbar and the first and the last section to remain the same but when I give the navbar a position of fixed it remain fixed there but all the other sections when scrolled down move through it like on top of it
And also if I give the position fixed to the first section it will be like this.
PS: I am using Tailwind CSS

The code:
https://gist.github.com/itisMilan/52ea39f41029b1dc674136b2ad7204b5

Answer (score 2):

You could restructure your layout as a grid, and have the middle content element by scrollable. See [this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/f5PapMSJ54).